# Filtering Gmail on From field

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

When I create a Gmail filter using the `FROM` field, do I want to enter the entire sender address or can I just use the name Google puts in the Inbox's from column?  And, if I want to trap a string of words, how do I enter the string? With " or '?

Answer (score 1):

Gmail filters don't reach out to your contacts, so you want to use a fully-qualified email address.

As for strings in your filter, unless you're looking to exact match on multiple words, you shouldn't need any quotes. If you do, either should suffice.